# passing a csv through an API

Tags: python, api, csv, aws-lambda

I'm trying to pass a csv through an api like this:

The csv is as follow:

```
field_1, field_2, field_3
1, 3, 7
```

the push code is this:

```
with open("sample_csv.csv") as f:
    data = {"file": f}
    print(data)
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "text/csv",
        "File-Type": "POS",
        "File-Key": "somekey",
    }

    r = requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers)
```

However when i read it from a Lambda on the other end i get this:

```
b'file=field_1%2C+field_2%2C+field_3%0A&file=1%2C+3%2C+7'
```

When i run the above string through chardet it tells me its ascii, but i dont know how to convert it

---

edit: lambda function code:

```
def main(event: dict, context) -> dict:
  body = base64.b64decode(event["body"])
  print(body)
```

Comment: I suspect this is more of a problem how you wrote that lambda function.

Comment: i added the lambda function code

Comment: so, that's not a lambda function; that's an assignment, and these can't happen in a [Python lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions). I'm a bit confused. Who executes that line of code? Why do you base64-decode things here?

Comment: i'm sorry i should've been more clear, its an aws lambda function. i'm not sure i should even base 64 encode it

Comment: You might be looking for urldecode, not base64-decode

Comment: hmm i just get a long list of gibberish characters if i apply unquote() (i assume that's what you meant?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, adding answer here for posterity

```
decoded_event = base64.b64decode(event["body"])
parsed_event = urllib.parse.parse_qs(x.decode())["file"]
```

After which `parsed_event` is a list with each element being a line of the csv which you can then manipulate as needed.